# Rebuilding a custom package from scratch

Tags: compiling

I have built and installed a package named `to-build`.

My file hierarcy looks like this:

```
$HOME/usr/
    src/
        to-build/
    packages
        bin/     include/ lib/     share/
```

I built and installed `to-build` this way:

```
$ cd $HOME/usr/src/to-build
$ mkdir builddir
$ cd buiddir
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr/packages
$ make 
$ make install
```

Let's say I installed other packages in `$HOME/usr/packages` and I have to re-build from scratch `to-build` because I forgot to specify a parameter with the `configure` command. Can I simply run the `configure, make, make install` commands or should I delete files that have previously been installed in `$HOME/usr/packages`? If the latter, how can I tell for sure which files in `$HOME/usr/packages` are related to `to-build`?

Comment: starting the whole process from the beginning SHOULD in most cases work without issues. BUT there may be some files left on your system, that are not built with your new parameters but were built with the old parameter set.

Comment: The answer to this question probably depends on how the makefiles of to-build work. Some of them even support `make uninstall`, but not all do. If you want to make sure that everything works correctly, you should remove the existing files.

Comment: What package system are you using? (Probably equivalently: what Unix variant are you running?)